# Link one page to another by user <a> tag in PHP

Tags: php, html

Here is my code of my poster in one page

```
 <a href="#"><img href="#"></a>
```

Now I want to link this to another page suppose I click on say for a href="mydomain.com/1"
it will redirect to another page and play that only file.Code for that page is

```
 if($playlistitem<=18)
  { 

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li class="xtitle">'.$post->title.'</li>';
echo '<li class="xdesc">'.$post->description.'</li>';

$dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';


echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';

$dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content->attributes()->url);
 echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
 echo '</ul>';
$playlistitem++;


 }
```

Whos ouptut is

```
<ul>
  <li class="xtitle">Breathing</li>
   <li class="xdesc">Roman Kogler (Thomas Schubert) is 19 years old and</li>
  <li class="xpreview">http://spoti.com/images/media/14496l.jpg</li>
    <li class="xsources_mp4">http://uk.clip- 1.filmtrailer.com9235_33612_a_5.mp4?log_var=179|341100232-1|-</li>
   <li class="xsources_webm">http://uk.clip-1.filmtrailer.com/9235_33612_a_5.webm?log_var=179|341100232-1|-</li></ul>
```

Comment: @Shredder- I want to link image of one page if user click on image then it redirect to second page and play particular video of same image which I have in first page

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data to another page, you could append to the URL in a GET fashion.

For example:

```
<a href="www.mydomain.com/show.php?img=myimage.jpg">Get Details</a>
```

Here, we are passing a value `myimage.jpg` to the `show.php` page.

So, in `show.php` page, you could access this data using the `$_GET`.
For example:

```
<?php
$img_name = $_GET['img']; //will get the value "myimage.jpg"
//... use this data to do whatever you need
?>
```

Comment: It's not working actually as you can see my code there is xml file so for every image we have to pass every if condition which make program slow.I want to implement in such a way like ?#tab1 in image and it will redirect to that particular content

Comment: sorry, can you rephrase your question by providing more clear description about the issue as well as by providing more details. I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Actually I am using here the xml code as you can see
Now I want to link in such a way suppose I want to play video file at 3rd position so I will write www.mydomain.com/#tab3 or something at tab3 so that only that file will play in this way I want to link the file from that image file if I give the path of that domain only that file will play