# Link one page to another page of the content by using <a> tag in PHP

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Link one page to another by user <a> tag in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256109/link-one-page-to-another-by-user-a-tag-in-php)

I am making poster which have a pic of all the videos of another page when I click on one image it will redirect to other page which have video of same pic.How it can be done.

Code of 1st page:

```
 $rss=new SimpleXMLElement($crxml);
$playlistitem=1;
foreach($rss->channel->item as $post)
{
   if($playlistitem<=18)
{    
    echo'<li>';
    $dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo '<a href="./video/#tab'.$playlistitem.'">';
    echo '<img src="'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'">';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<span>'.$post->title.'</span>';
    $playlistitem++;
    }
    }
```

Second page code:

```
echo '<a name="tab'.$playlistitem.'">';
echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';

echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
      echo '</a>';
echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';

$dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content->attributes()->url);
 echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
 echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a link, or how to specify a URL?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams-specify a url

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran yeah we are in team that why same.Actually we want to spechify the url in such a way that it open same video you can visit tv.spoti.com and suppose I want to see only 3rd video so link in such a way that it play 3rd video only

Comment: Reposting isn't allowed.